# How to calculate Date Difference in pyspark or python?

Tags: python, database, datetime, validation, pyspark

Here is my input table:

```
Name            Date
Nancy           2021-08-14
Rictk           2021-08-15
Francky         2021-08-16
Nancy           2021-08-18
Nancy           2022-02-07
Francky         2021-12-06
```

So here I want to calculate day difference between two unique name records,
for Example- Nancy has Three records but we only needs to take top two records and calculate day difference between them (take only first two record for every person). if there is only one record for a person then return as 0.

I want output dataframe like

```
Name            Date            Day
Nancy           2021-08-14      4
Rictk           2021-08-15      0
Francky         2021-08-16      6
Nancy           2021-08-18      4
Nancy           2022-02-07      4
Francky         2021-08-22      6
```

Explanation- Nancy has 4 days because here we consider top two records of Nancy and the date was 2021-08-14 and 2021-08-18 so there is 4 days gap. likewise same for remaining all.

So how I can do this in pyspark or python.

Comment: *top 2* records meaning if ordered by date descending? Or just the top 2 in the table? In Spark casual top without ordering can be not deterministic... So I hope you mean ordering by date descending...

Comment: @ZygD - just top 2, no any condition for that

Comment: Then I doubt you need Spark. For this task data should reside in one node, while in Spark it's distributed. So without order column you couldn't tell which Nancy is first from 3 Nancys on 3 separate nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your output and input dataset values do not match , hence you would see a difference in the results

You can achieve this with a combination of [LEAD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lead.html?highlight=lead) & [DATEDIFF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.datediff.html) Partitioned by - `Name` & Ordered By - `Date` and only take the MIN of the datediff and propagate it to your input set

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
Name,Date
Nancy,2021-08-14
Rictk,2021-08-15
Francky,2021-08-16
Nancy,2021-08-18
Nancy,2022-02-07
Francky,2021-12-06
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
             .withColumn('Date',F.to_date(F.col('date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))\
             .orderBy(*[F.col('Name'),F.col('Date')])

sparkDF.show()

+-------+----------+
|   Name|      Date|
+-------+----------+
|Francky|2021-08-16|
|Francky|2021-12-06|
|  Nancy|2021-08-14|
|  Nancy|2021-08-18|
|  Nancy|2022-02-07|
|  Rictk|2021-08-15|
+-------+----------+
```

#### Lead & DateDiff - Date

Generate Lead values for the combination of Name & Date

```
window = Window.partitionBy('Name').orderBy(F.col('Date'))

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('lead_date',F.lead(F.col('Date'),-1).over(window))

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('lead_date_diff', F.datediff(
                                                           F.lead(F.col('Date'),1).over(window)
                                                          ,F.col('Date')
                                                        )
                                            )
sparkDF.show()

+-------+----------+----------+--------------+
|   Name|      Date| lead_date|lead_date_diff|
+-------+----------+----------+--------------+
|  Rictk|2021-08-15|      null|          null|
|  Nancy|2021-08-14|      null|             4|
|  Nancy|2021-08-18|2021-08-14|           173|
|  Nancy|2022-02-07|2021-08-18|          null|
|Francky|2021-08-16|      null|           112|
|Francky|2021-12-06|2021-08-16|          null|
+-------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

#### Join

Finally aggregate the above resultset to only take the MIN of datediff & merge it with your input set

```
sparkDFAgg = sparkDF.groupby('Name').agg(F.min(F.col('lead_date_diff')).alias('Day'))\
                    .select(*[F.col('Name').alias('Name_Key'),F.col('Day')])

sparkDF = sparkDF.join(sparkDFAgg
                    ,sparkDF['Name'] == sparkDFAgg['Name_Key']
                    ,'left'
          ).select(sparkDF['Name']
                   ,sparkDF['Date']
                   ,sparkDFAgg['Day']
          ).fillna(0)


sparkDF.show()

+-------+----------+---+
|   Name|      Date|Day|
+-------+----------+---+
|  Rictk|2021-08-15|  0|
|  Nancy|2021-08-14|  4|
|  Nancy|2021-08-18|  4|
|  Nancy|2022-02-07|  4|
|Francky|2021-08-16|112|
|Francky|2021-12-06|112|
+-------+----------+---+
```

**Note - You can further reduce your computation by only taking the first 2 records for generating the `lead_date_diff` column pre-filtering**

Answer (score -1):

in order to calculate the gap between 2 dates you need to first convert the time string into a `datetime` object like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-08-18', '%Y-%m-%d')
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-08-14', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

- note that you must provide the correct datetime format so that your input string would be parsed correctly.

after you created above objects you can use the `-` operator to calculated the difference between the two dates and extract the days parameter:

```
diff = date1 - date2
diff_days = diff.days
```